# Can I emulate graphical DOS applications inside a TTY?

Tags: command-line, tty, dosbox

Can I play DOS games inside a hard terminal (like the ones that open with Control+Alt+F1)?

I want to be able to close the Xsession because the PC I'm doing this is on is really slow. The PC has enough power to run Xubuntu and a dos emulator on it but I'd just like to learn if there is a way to play games with just a plain terminal.

Comment: If you're not looking for the graphical environment you could just use Ubuntu server instead...

Comment: This is not the place to discuss what is distro is faster. Use [chat].

Answer (score 5):

Sure, with `dosbox`; enable the `universe` repository in Software & Updates then search it within Ubuntu Software Center, or run this command in a Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install dosbox
```

Then switch to a `TTY` with, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and run it with this command:

```
dosbox
```

Comment: Have you tried this in a TTY? I won't deny it loads but it looks like something [graphically] exploded over my screen and I can't read any of it. It might just be my graphics. It might work fine on a KMS-based terminal.

Comment: @Oli Oh dear. No, of course I didn't. Let me research on this a bit